# Is there something similar to Firejail for OpenBSD?

Tags: web-browser, sandbox, openbsd

On Linux, Firejail (https://firejail.wordpress.com/) offers an easy way to sandbox web browsers and other programs.

Is there an easy way to sandbox a web browser on OpenBSD ?

(reserve question: is there a non-easy way ?)

Answer (score 2):

Some developers [are working on a sandboxed version of Chromium](http://openbsd-archive.7691.n7.nabble.com/unveil-2-usage-in-base-td348025.html). I don't know if there is a public diff or not. With *pledge* and *unveil*, they can limit the syscalls used and the directories viewed by Chromium.

Firefox only uses *pledge*, so it has not whitelisted/blacklisted directories.

Comment: Thanks for the link on _unveil_.
I was aware of _pledge_ in OpenBSD Chromium, it seems to me that in Linux Chromium implements a similar function leveraging seccomp-bfp and namespaces.
- see chromium://sandbox on Linux -

Comment: Yes, both are similar but you can't disable the sandbox on OpenBSD because the sandbox restrictions are part of the code of Chromium or Firefox. The OpenBSD developers are using the layers separation which both browsers include for Linux.